# SSRS 2014 snipping off the end of text in a tablix row?

Tags: reporting-services

We recently upgraded our SQL 2005 reports to SQL 2014.  They all seem to work just fine with one exception.  When the text in a row approaches the right margin and the word ALMOST fits, SSRS seems to have an issue in wrapping the word, instead the end of the cell cuts off the part of the last letter.  Most all of our reports use Times New Roman and the only solution we've found that works consistently is changing the font from TNR to something like Tahoma. No amount of shrinking the column or changing the right margin will work.  There has to be another solution.

Comment: Is the CanGrow set to True for the column?

Comment: Yes.  It's a merged set of 3 columns.

Comment: The only other suggestion I would have is to verify that the right margin on the report does not cover the right margin of the tablix.  This would cause it to cut off also.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I tried shrinking the field in the tablix row so that it was smaller than the defined margin.  Still had the problem.